# salesforce forcejs not getting refresh token

Tags: salesforce, sfdc, salesforce-development

i am using forcejs in my angular app which is working fine and gives me accessToken. However, I am not able to get refreshToken to be able to renew accessToken as needed. The code is below

```
import { OAuth, DataService } from 'forcejs';

 async loginSFDC(){
    let callbackUrl = 'https://my.callback.url'

    let oauth = OAuth.createInstance('client key','', callbackUrl);
    oauth.login().then(
      
      async (oauthResult) => {
            DataService.createInstance(oauthResult);
            console.log("Logged Into Salesforce Successfully:::" + JSON.stringify(oauthResult)); 
           
    });
  }
```

the above code is printing accessToken but no refreshToken. Please advise

i have also tried passing the 2nd parameter in createInstance as http://login.salesfoce.com?scope=full+refresh_token but that does not work as url gets constructed wrong on adding the scope=full+refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code of [forcejs](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs/blob/master/src/data-service.js), you can use the refreshAccessToken() method with the DataService instance you created.

Comment: based on my understanding nowhere it is generating refreshToken. it is actually assuming it is already generated and using it to generate accessToken

Comment: could you check what are the current scopes that your app is working with? I presume that if it doesn't have the refresh_token scope configured, it won't return a refresh token. have you tried to add the refresh_token scope to allow for it to be generated in your app? https://pasteboard.co/JyetnRa.png. you can also find out here the 
explanation about the refresh token - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks look at my screenshot and i have it alread https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbz589vnx8l9hge/Screen%20Shot%202020-10-31%20at%209.34.05%20PM.png?dl=0

The link you pointed does not show anything missed. ideally, forcejs api should return me this without doing anything else. but i dont know why it does not

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging it is discovered that the refresh token shows up when my code is running on localhost but does not when it is deployed to the the webserver. i dont know how to debug further or fix it. but i have verified that this behavior is consistently reproducible